# How to implement a near-singleton?

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns, singleton

I sometimes have a need for classes that should only be instantiated once during the lifecycle of the application.  Making them singletons is bad because then unit testing becomes problematic.

But still, because there should be one and only instance of such objects during the lifecycle of my application, it would be an error to ever instantiate such an object twice *when the application is running*.

Hence I'd like my app to throw an exception as soon as it detects, during its lifecycle, that such an object is instantiated twice *while still allowing several instantiation of such an object while unit testing*.

I think it's not an unreasonable requirement: if during one lifecycle of the application only one such object should be created then throwing an exception seems like a correct thing to do.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
/**
 * The key words "MUST", "MUST NOT", "REQUIRED", "SHALL", "SHALL NOT",
 * "SHOULD", "SHOULD NOT", "RECOMMENDED", "MAY", and "OPTIONAL" in this
 * document are to be interpreted as described in RFC 2119.
 *
 * You MUST NOT instantiate this class more than once during the application's
 * lifecycle.  If you try to do so, an exception SHALL be thrown.
 *
 * You SHOULD be able to instantiate this class more than once when unit
 * testing.
 *
 * 
 */
public class LifeCycle {

    private static final AtomicInteger cnt = new AtomicInteger( 0 );

    @NotNull
    public static LifeCycle getNewLifeCycle() {
        if ( cnt.incrementAndGet() > 1 && App.isRealApp() ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Class is already instantiated");
        }
        return new LifeCycle();
    }

}
```

where *App.isRealApp()* shall always return *false* when I'm unit testing and always *true* when the real app is running.

My question is simple: does it makes sense and how am I supposed to implement this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your design requires a singleton, then you're best off with a singleton rather than trying something complicated.

*If* your trouble in unit testing singletons is getting an instance to mock, for example, then I'd create an instantiable lightweight proxy that provides the same interface as your singleton.

The proxy should have no logic -- it should just map calls through to the singleton.

You can then use it in tests, and leave the codebase with singleton intact. The lightweight proxy can remain part of the testing suite, and not be released.

Comment: It's worked for me -- and meant I could keep the codebase as it was.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use a dependency-injection framework like Spring.

The application configuration would specify the singleton instances, but your test cases could still create as-needed instances and inject them manually.

For more information: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html

An alternative, if you've already got static singleton references sprinkled throughout your code, is to convert your `Singleton.getInstance()` method into a true factory, using a system property to control its behavior. This system property could be as simple as a flag to indicate that testing is in process, or as complex as the name of another class to use as the real factory (similar to what the JDK does with `DocumentBuilderFactory`).

Comment: @Anon: +1 too... I find it very interesting that Spring can be configured at the application level to allow only a singleton while still allowing unit testing.  Cool, I will read on it.

Comment: Isn't a complex framework like Spring far to complex for such a simple problem? I think the answer is quite clear. You should write your test code so that you can test the code and not change the code to make it testable.

Comment: Spring might be a bit much, but a factory that controls instance creation is basically the same thing for this purpose, and a lot more lightweight, as long as the refactoring load isn't too high.

Comment: @Roflcoptr - if you don't make your code testable, than you're limited in the amount of testing that you can do. For example, if your singleton represents a database connection, you must always have that connection available to run the test. And you can't write one test that exercises behavior when the connection is available and another that exercises behavior when it isn't, or when it fails halfway through the test.

Comment: @Anon: Yes I think you should test your code, but I think you shouldn't change anything in your produciton code for the sole purpose of testing.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: but that is not entirely correct: if your code cannot be easily unit tested then it is probably very bad code.

Comment: A simpler dependency-injection tool that supports this near-singleton pattern is Google guice -- http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/.

Answer (score 0):

> Hence I'd like my app to throw an exception as soon as it detects, during its lifecycle, that such an object is instantiated twice

That's what the Singleton enforces.

> while still allowing several instantiation of such an object while unit testing.

You can make enforce this with [@com.dp4j.Singleton](http://dp4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/dp4j/Singleton.html)

That's what the Reflection API allows.

You can either use the Reflection API directly or have dp4j inject it for you. [Here](http://dp4j.com) you will find code for both.